# create vertical tabs in tabpane javafx

Tags: tabs, javafx, scenebuilder

By default if I create a TabPane in Scene Builder and add tabs they are in horizontal order on the top of TabPane, how can I add vertical tabs on the left side of TabPane?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just select "LEFT" under the dropdown for "Side":

[image]

Comment: thanks, Is there any way to make tabs text horizontal?

Comment: See: [JavaFX 2.0 TabPane : Tabs at left and keep tab header horizontal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708578/javafx-2-0-tabpane-tabs-at-left-and-keep-tab-header-horizontal)